# fstab filesystem editing

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, fstab

```
UUID=f5be9b96-da41-49fd-a8e2-dbbf37f5cd7d       /       ext4      defaults,usrquota       1       1
UUID=31a1c8d1-18ee-4c97-a0b9-b92599247112 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=1fc6e1e3-bb0e-46bd-9de8-b8a11ca69ab9       /home   ext4    defaults,noexec,usrquota,noatime        1      2
UUID=17dd0442-1872-476e-bb86-d5bf8c2f86f6 /tmp                    ext4    loop,rw,noexec,nosuid        1 2
UUID=dc212bbf-cce5-4663-872c-390e808c3f1e swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   noexec,nosuid        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
```

Do I need to remove the defaults in order to make the noexec for /home work? Would I need to also add the rw and some other replacements to it that are normally included.

This is a webserver.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the defaults. It's a "noop". You can add the specific options you need without specifying `defaults`.

See:

```
UUID=1a09013e-31cf-49d9-96ef-c583821b6ff7 /          ext4    noatime         1 1
UUID=5e34ada8-9040-472d-bd6d-606e9d66a2bd /boot      ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=ac19298a-102c-40bc-93d3-05611f1b9289 /tmp       xfs     defaults        1 2
UUID=e22e51aa-8c0d-4c41-8d81-c55f200d74db /usr       ext4    noatime         1 2
UUID=bb2fd699-5955-4ebb-88aa-00dcad177ba8 /var       xfs     noatime,logbufs=8,logbsize=256k 1 2
UUID=e6697261-98a5-42d9-8c48-b09a09544d1c swap       swap    defaults        0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The only use of `defaults` is... as a default. If `defaults` didn't exist, how would you specify "no options" if consecutive spaces are treated as a single one? (Without `''`)